# Вычисление рейтинга в диапазоне от 0 до 5

Tags: алгоритм

Как лучше вычислить значение рейтинга от 0 до 5

- 0 - минимальный рейтинг
- 5 - максимальный рейтинг

Допустим

```
 - Лайков 20422 
 - Дизлайков 1002


 - Лайков 0 
 - Дизлайков 1002


 - Лайков 20422 
 - Дизлайков 0
```

Как в данном случаи получить результат? C плавающей запятой, после запятой не более 1 цифры, в десятых.

Comment: А формула какая?

Comment: Вот я и хочу узнать что за формула будет

Comment: Так вы принципы опишите, а там видно будет

Comment: Есть количество лайков и дизлайков, данное соотношение необходимо привести от 0 до 5 с плавающей точкой. В десятичных

Comment: Если лайков меньше дизлайков, это может быть 0. Если лайков больше дизлайков, делим лайки на дизлайки, в данном случае если результат больше 5, так и оставить можно. Можно поиграться с округлением, если число не целое. Обычно рейтинг от 0 до 5 делается с предоставлением пользователю поставить конкретную отметку(число), а не просто лайк или дизлайк. В данном случае корректно разве что можно вывести их соотношение.

Comment: @Merantory И один лайк при нуле дизлайков куда лучше чем 100 при одном? :)

Comment: @Harry, психологически лайк должен быть ценнее дизлайка. Критика даётся легко, похвала - тяжело.

Comment: то, что вам требуется, в статистике называется нормализация данных. почитайте, просветитесь. // p.s. а чтобы наблюдения (это статистический такой термин) можно было нормализовать, преобразуйте их по какой-нибудь формуле. ну, например, `кл*л+кд*д`, где `л` и `д` — количество лайков и дизлайков, а `кл` и `кд` — некоторые подходящие вам коэффициенты, например, `1` и `-1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант - реализовать самым банальным способом, изначально высчитывать рейтинг от `0` до `1`, а затем умножать его на `5`.

Также, нужно не забыть о граничном случае, и когда оценок нет - возвращать рейтинг `0`.

**Как это будет выглядеть:**

Пусть, рейтинг - это отношение числа лайков к общему числу оценок.

Тогда, в случае:

```
 - Лайков 20422 
 - Дизлайков 1002
```

Имеем:  `20422 / (20422 + 1002) = 0.9532 * 5 = 4.766 ~ 4.8`.

**Общая формула**: `5 * (x / (x + y))`, где `x` - количество лайков, `y` - количество дизлайков.

И в вариантах:

```
 - Лайков 0 
 - Дизлайков 1002


 - Лайков 20422 
 - Дизлайков 0
```

Согласно формуле получаем `0` и `5`, соответственно.

**P.S** А вообще, это только один из вариантов (самый очевидный) и придумать их можно очень много, в зависимости от логики вашего проекта.

Comment: Как можно исправить php8. Если лайков 0 и дизлайков. Выдает как за ошибку, выставлять проверку? Возможно выйти из положения без условий if else?

Comment: @Лена отдельно перед алгоритмом проверяйте этот граничный случай и выдавайте 0

Comment: В отсутствиие дизлайков, любое число лайков ценится одинаково. Это плохо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это ведь легко решается при выводе - сортировкой записей в бд по двум полям, первоначально по рейтингу, а вторично по количеству лайков, отдельно с рейтингом в такой ситуации особо не разгуляешься

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что-то типа `4p/(p+m)+[m==0]p/(p+1)`? p - лайки, m - дизлайки

Comment: Задача так и формулируется "как можно разгуляться с одним числом - рейтингом". Ваш рейтинг - функция отношения лайк/дизлайк. Можно ли сделать лучше?

Comment: @Harry, надо собрать требования к рейтингу. Например: "при равном числе дизлайков, рейтинг больше там где больше лайков", "рейтинг - непрерывная (гладкая) функция своих аргументов" и т.п. Затем можно искать примеры функций подходящих под требования. Может быть, ваш пример хорош - будут требования, будет о чём говорить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy лучше может быть и можно, но, честно говоря, совсем не вижу необходимости в этом, считаю даже такой примитивный вариант допустимым в применении, потому что всегда можно осуществить последующую фильтрацию по всевозможным хотелкам, а если рейтинги (не позиции) у записей 500/0 и 300/0 будут отличаться, то на мой взгляд - это странновато..

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но спорить не буду, я лишь предоставил один из возможных вариантов, за оптимальность точно не борюсь :)

Comment: Для меня между 1/0 и 10000/0 огромная разница.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy эту разницу можно учесть и запись 1/0 поместить в самом конце записей с рейтингом 5, а 10000/0 - первой